# How to Change Xcode development region to print localized string using NSLog

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

Documentation of `operatingSystemVersionString` method of `NSProcessInfo` says "The operating system version string is human readable, localized, and is appropriate for displaying to the user. This string is not appropriate for parsing."

```
NSString *versionString = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] operatingSystemVersionString];
NSLog(@"%@",versionString);
```

I want to check what it will return in case of other languages like China, French. I changed region and language but NSLog always prints in english language.What settings I should change in Xcode and System Preferences to check the behavior of `operatingSystemVersionString` based on region and language? Or NSLog prints in English only?

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSProcessInfo_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSProcessInfo/operatingSystemVersionString

Comment: How did you change the region and language?

Comment: @Wain Language and Text under System Preferences.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding these lines in the main.m file

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"en", nil] forKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Just change the 2 letter prefix (@"en") to any language you need.